# Webdriver timeout exception with elements inside div

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to click on comment area(add a public comment) under YouTube video using Selenium WebDriver (C#).

But Selenium don't recognize elements under div with id="header". [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3d34.png)
This code works correctly:

```
    var element = driver
        .FindElement(By.Id("comments"))
        .FindElement(By.Id("header"));
```

But in this case it returns empty collection:

```
    var elements = driver
        .FindElement(By.Id("comments"))
        .FindElement(By.Id("header"))
        .FindElements(By.Id("placeholder-area"));
```

I already tried driver.SwitchTo() with frames but it doesn't help

Also I tried

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

        wait.Until(d => d
        .FindElement(By.Id("comments"))
        .FindElement(By.Id("header")).Displayed);
```

And i got Webdriver timeout exception [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m3Uo.png)

And after i tried

```
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

        wait.Until(d => d
        .FindElement(By.Id("comments"))
        .FindElement(By.Id("header")).Enabled);

        var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("comments"))
        .FindElement(By.Id("header")).FindElement(By.Id("simple-box"));
```

I just got NoSuchElementException for simple-box

```
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

        wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("comments"))
        .FindElement(By.Id("header")).FindElement(By.Id("simple-box")).Enabled);
```

Also i tried with full xpath to current element

```
        var element = driver
            .FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='simple-box']"));

        var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[4]/div[1]/div/ytd-comments/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[1]/ytd-comments-header-renderer/div[5]"));
```

Comment: Are you sure that the HTML structure matches your expectation?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I have access to header but no access to simple-box. I don't know why

Comment: You can check on youtube video page and find comment area (add a public comment)

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried to find these elements in YouTube. Looks like the 'comments' section is not loaded fully. Try to scroll to the section first:

```
var comments = driver.FindElement(By.Id("comments"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript($"window.scrollTo({comments.Location.X}, {comments.Location.Y})");
```

And after that wait for header is displayed.

Comment: var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("comments"))
            .FindElement(By.Id("header"));

            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.MoveToElement(element);
            action.Perform();